# WP All Import plugin - Set permalink page

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

I am working on a massive pages (more than 70,000 pages) integration project, thanks to WP All Import I can create pages with datas from my csv file, the problem here is that i want set permalink in according to some values of my CSV file ().

[Capture WP All Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7iTI.png)

For example I want to create URL :

```
website.com/destinations/UK/london
website.com/destinations/UK/london/agency1
website.com/destinations/UK/london/agency2
website.com/destinations/FR/paris
website.com/destinations/FR/paris/agency1
website.com/destinations/FR/paris/agency2
```

Country (UK, FR....) equal a column in my CSV file
City (london, paris....) equal a column in my CSV file
Agency (agency1, agency2....) equal a column in my CSV file

Someone can help me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: When it comes to backups, I only trust BackupBuddy. It's the non-plus ultra. Check it out here: https://gitlab.com/wordpress-premium

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can update the entire permalink, but you could probably update the post slug (the `post_name` column in `wp_posts` table) with something similar to this (untested):

```
function my_saved_post( $post_id, $xml_node, $is_update ) {

    // Retrieve the import ID.
    $import_id = ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ? $_GET['id'] : ( isset( $_GET['import_id'] ) ? $_GET['import_id'] : 'new' ) );

    // Only run for import 8. TODO: Change this to your import ID!
    if ( $import_id == '8' ) {

        // Convert SimpleXml object to array for easier use.
        $record = json_decode( json_encode( ( array ) $xml_node ), 1 );

        // verify post is not a revision
        if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

            // update the post slug
            wp_update_post( array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_name' => $record['pays'] . '/' . $record['typedelieu']
            ));
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'pmxi_saved_post', 'my_saved_post', 10, 3 );
```

Inspired by [documentation](https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/action-reference/#pmxi_saved_post) and [this SE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105936).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, where I wanted to use the SKU value in my CSV file instead of the Product Slug for the URL. So I used the free Permalink Manager Lite (https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/) together with WP All Import to achieve this.

It seems to me you could drag any combination of your values from the CSV file into the Permalink Manager text box.

[WP ALL Import Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWRAT.png)